# SSRS how to show report without executing it immediately

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdl

So, the problem is that report on SSRS is executing immediately after opening. I use query based default parameters.. And i saw the solution with adding additional parameter without default value. It doesn't work for me because of the textbox which cannot be hidden (i tried to hide it and report stop working).
So is there a way to hide this additional parameter? or maybe another way to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try set it as an internal parameter? When you set it as hidden did you set allow blank value and allow null value?

Comment: Yep.. it also throws an error.. About blank and null values, no :) wait i try it..

Comment: What do you mean `report on SSRS is executing immediately after opening`? I believe you do have to click on "View Report".

Comment: Always errors :( when hidden error says that there is no value for parameter A. For internal it's impossible to provide valid values for parameters. (Text in english maybe different, because it's my translation from russian localization :))

Comment: Is your report deployed to a Sharepoint/.net portal? That's the only case I can think of.

Comment: Sourav_Agasti, no i'm not pressing view report, just pressing on the report in the report manager and it starts executing.

Comment: What is .net portal? i used sql reporting service and use report manager to see the reports, there isn't other environment.

Comment: Ignore that. I got your issue. Will come up with a solution

Comment: @user2931031 - What is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: If i use hidden parameter: there is no value for parameter A, (simple text without parameters form) If i use internal - Error checking parameters.it's impossible to provide valid values for parameters (rsParameterError). Also  i repeat that i have no english version.. this is my translation of errors from russian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because you are setting a required parameter as nullable or you are giving it a default value that is invalid.  To fix the problem, remove the default values.  When you go to the report it will not be able to run until you give it the required value(s).

Comment: I cannot remove default values, because i have to use query based default values. Users want to see default values but want to have an ability to change some of them before executing report. Now they have to press cancel and then they can change some parameters.

Comment: The list of choices can be given from a query without picking one of them as a default value.  Also, if you are setting any of the parameters as `nullable`, but they are required to have a value, this can also cause a problem.

Comment: Thanks, maybe changing one of existing parameters to not nullable will be allowed in my case.. Anyway maybe there are other solutions which will not change existing parameters..

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solutions to it.

1. Set the default of the parameter in question to such a value that would absolutely have no matches in dataset.  Say for example, the parameter is Location. Give the defalut value as "Mars". (Unless of course you build software of extra terrestrial beings). This way the report will execute pretty fast, without any errors.
2. Set the default value of the parameter to be `NULL`. Add a dataset filter like below:

   ```
   =IIF(ISNOTHING(Parameters!Location.Value), TRUE, FALSE)
   ```

   [image]

Using `IsNothing` function you can ask dataset to return rows only when the parameter has values.

Let me know if either approach works out.

Comment: Both of this works.. but not in my case :( 1 - is not working because i dont' use available values, query used only for default parameters, but any value is allowed. 2. if i set filter for main dataset SSRS starts executing at least parameters query, so the removing "allow null" option will be better because both of this solutions require that default value query return null

Comment: Did you try option 2? `ISNOTHING(Parameters!Location.Value)` gives you the value of the parameter(default value in your case). The `IIF` basically fails the `TRUE = TRUE` validation and forces the dataset to give no records.

Comment: I tried.. after adding this filter to the main dataset report started executing... Maybe this is due to i have many datasets, and it used to fill headers, footers, parameters, some inner data... I used data extension. I didn't said about it, but maybe in this case it's important. Maybe if i add that filter to all datasets excluding parameters dataset it will work\

Comment: I tried for all datasets.. but it looks like this filter is applied after report execution.

Comment: Try changing the expression a bit....`=IIF(ISNOTHING(Parameters!Location.Value), FALSE, TRUE)`. Here I ha e changed the positions of boolean values.

Comment: Yes, i've seen this and tried.. and it's working as i wrote in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am necroing this thread, but in case someone sees it...

What I do to combat this is add a parameter in my stored procedures called @runReady int = 3

Then I have:

```
if @runReady = 1
  Begin
    Execute my code
  End
```

Then I have a parameter in my SSRS called with available values of View Only = 1, Update Records = 2 (I use this because I have stored procedures that run DB updates, as well), and Do Not Execute = 3 and default it to three. That way, all my other parameters are set and will only execute the report when someone changes it to the correct value.